Numbering correctly subfigures
I have a Supplementary material where my figures are labelled with A, B, C, etc....
When I insert subfigures and call in the text, the numbering are wrong.
I would like to print: Figure A(a) instead 1(a).
The reference for the main figure is ok.
Can help me please?
Here, my MWE:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}


\begin{document}


\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}

\section*{Supplementary material}

See figure \ref{construida}

See figure \ref{construida-melhorada}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\subfigure[first]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{}\label{construida}}
\hfill 
\subfigure[second]{
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{}\label{melhorada-phase1}}
\caption{a main caption}
\label{construida-melhorada}
\end{figure}

\end{document}



The subfigure package has been obsolete and deprecated since 2002. Don't use it. In its place, use either subfig or subcaption.

Did the provided answer solve your problem? If yes then consider accepting it. The same is true for other questions of you

The subigure package is deprecated.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\labelformat{subfigure}{\thefigure(#1)}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Alph{figure}}

\section*{Supplementary material}

See figure \ref{construida}

See figure \ref{construida-melhorada}

\begin{figure}[!htbp]

\centering
\subfloat[first\label{construida}]{%
  \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{}%
}\hfill 
\subfloat[second\label{melhorada-phase1}]{%
    \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{}%
}
\caption{a main caption}
\label{construida-melhorada}

\end{figure}

\end{document}


